# CSS put in block not reflecting in magento 2

Tags: product, blocks, product-view

in magento 2.3.5p2

In Admin Panel **Content > Elements > Blocks**

a Block has been created to showcase a list of products for promotion

The content of the block is as below

```
<img src="{{media url="03-EVENT-PAGES/9-9-extra-vaganza/WOWSHOP-9.9-EXTRA-VAGANZA_TV-LandingPage.jpg"}}" alt="" width="100%"> <br><br>{{widget type="MageBig\WidgetPlus\Block\Product" product_type="featured" product_ids="36789,63076,59775,61807,59511" product_style="1" cache_lifetime="86400" limit="5" countdown="0" slider="1" row="1" margin="30" navigation="0" paging="0" column="5" x1600="items:5,nav:true" x1200="items:5,nav:true" x992="items:3,nav:true" x768="items:3,nav:true" x576="items:2,nav:true" x0="items:2,nav:true" template="widget/product01.phtml"}} <br><br><img src="{{media url="03-EVENT-PAGES/9-9-extra-vaganza/WOWSHOP-9.9-EXTRA-VAGANZA_ECMC-LandingPage.jpg"}}" alt="" width="100%">
<script>
  const collection = window.getElementsByClassName("product-item");

  collection.style.removeProperty('max-width');
</script>
<style>

  .dropdown {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    width: auto;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 4px;
    summary {
      padding: 1rem;
    }
    summary::-webkit-details-marker {
      display: none; 
    }
    &__panel {
      padding: 15px;
      background-color: #fff;
    }
    h4.cs-title {
      text-transform: uppercase;
      font-size: 16px;
      padding: 15px 0px 0px;
      color: #000;
    }
    .tnc {
      font-size: 12px;
      padding: 15px 0px 0px;
    }
    ul {
      list-style-type: disc;
      margin: 0;
      list-style: none;
      padding-left: 0;
    }
    .bullet-sp {
      margin-left: 20px;
    }
    .showmobile {
      display: none;
    }


    @media only screen and (min-device-width: 480px) {

      .showpc {
        display: none;
      }

      .showmobile {
        display: block;
      }

      .categoryPack .subHeader a {
        width: 100%;
        left: 0;
      }

      summary{
        width: 86%;
        margin:auto;
      }
    }

    @media only screen and (min-device-width: 1025px) {

      .showpc {
        display: block;
      }

      .showmobile {
        display: none;
      }

      summary{
        width: 26%;
        margin: auto;
        font-size: 20pt;
      }
    }
    @media only screen and (min-width : 210px) and (max-width : 480px) {

      .showpc {
        display: none;
      }

      .showmobile {
        display: block;
      }
    }

    @media (max-width: 1199px)
      .page-products .category-products .product-items .product-item {
        -ms-flex: 0 1 33%;
        flex: 0 1 33%;
        max-width: 100% !important;
    }

</style>
```

Even thought the product element are showing, the css supposed to be able to reflect does not reflect, below attached the result of the block added

- The max width instead of 33% should be 100%

[image]

Showing the look of product image that is not responsive when the px got below 1199px

[image]

Please explain any fixture that can be done to fix this issue

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is, you didn't use CSS but LESS in your CMS block.
So in your frontend you also end up having LESS in your HTML code because cms blocks don't compile LESS -> CSS. And the browser also can't interprete LESS code.

You have two options to fix it:

1. Manually compile your LESS code into plain CSS (there are [online generators](https://jsonformatter.org/less-to-css) for it), then add the CSS to your CMS block
2. Remove the LESS code from your CMS block and in your theme (or a module) create a new LESS file and import it according to [Magento2 Documentation](https://developer.adobe.com/commerce/frontend-core/guide/css/preprocess/)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, I finally able to add the css fixture but instead of using css I use other method that is by using jquery to overwrite the css after the page is fully loaded